# USB OTG & sensors

Tags: usb, sensors, usb-otg

As I understand it, USB OTG requires specific hardware. I am curious if this is the case. But my broader question concerns connecting a device (PC, tablet) to a digital sensor. Does the device need to support OTG in order to connect to a digital sensor over USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be, "no," a digital sensor does not need to support OTG in order to be have host Android device connect to it.